# MaybeOwned implementation generic over ToOwned

Tags: rust, traits, ownership

I have the following trait:

```rust
/// A trait for accepting values which may or may not be owned.
trait MaybeOwned<B: ToOwned + ?Sized> {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool;
    fn into_owned(self) -> <B as ToOwned>::Owned;
    fn borrow(&self) -> &B;
}
```

An example for how I'd like it to behave:

```rust
fn mo_u32<T: MaybeOwned<u32>>(x: T) { println!("{} {}", x.is_owned(), x.borrow()); }
fn mo_str<T: MaybeOwned<str>>(x: T) { println!("{} {}", x.is_owned(), x.borrow()); }

fn main() {
    mo_u32(42);                  // true 42    
    mo_u32(&42);                 // false 42   
    mo_str("test");              // false test 
    mo_str("test".to_string());  // true test  
    mo_str(&"test".to_string()); // false test 
}
```

The purpose of it so that a function can be generic over owned and borrowed values, to  reduce the amount of unnecessary clones in our codebase (the types in question are large containers of data). It is also possible to do this by accepting `Cow` arguments, but this (depending on inlining) pushes the decision to runtime rather than compile time, and adds extra noise for callers.

### I was wondering, is it possible to implement this trait completely generically over `ToOwned` in stable Rust?

I have come up with an implementation that works, but is not generic over `ToOwned`. If you want `MaybeOwned<str>` to accept `String`s you need a separate implementation for that. This implementation is listed below, along with two examples for `String <-> str` and `Vec<T> <-> [T]` as well as `Cow`.

```rust
impl<T: ToOwned<Owned=T>> MaybeOwned<T> for T {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { true }
    fn into_owned(self) -> T { self }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &T { self }
}

impl<B: ToOwned + ?Sized> MaybeOwned<B> for &B {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { false }
    fn into_owned(self) -> <B as ToOwned>::Owned { self.to_owned() }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &B { self }
}

impl<B: ToOwned + ?Sized> MaybeOwned<B> for Cow<'_, B> {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { 
        match *self {
            Cow::Borrowed(_) => true,
            Cow::Owned(_) => false,
        }
    }
    fn into_owned(self) -> <B as ToOwned>::Owned { Cow::into_owned(self) }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &B { Borrow::borrow(self) }
}

impl MaybeOwned<str> for String {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { true }
    fn into_owned(self) -> String { self }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str { self }
}

impl MaybeOwned<str> for &String {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { false }
    fn into_owned(self) -> String { self.clone() }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str { self }
}

impl<T: Clone> MaybeOwned<[T]> for Vec<T> {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { true }
    fn into_owned(self) -> Vec<T> { self }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &[T] { self }
}

impl<T: Clone> MaybeOwned<[T]> for &Vec<T> {
    fn is_owned(&self) -> bool { false }
    fn into_owned(self) -> Vec<T> { self.clone() }
    fn borrow(&self) -> &[T] { self }
}
```

Comment: You can use something like [static_cow](https://docs.rs/static-cow/latest/static_cow/trait.IntoOwning.html) which would give you syntax like `mo_u32(Owned(42)); mo_u32(Borrowed(&42))`. This solves the problem of "pushes the decision to runtime rather than compile time" but not the other problem of "adds extra noise for callers". In general I think what you want is not possible because reference types look like values so the only impls which cover both ALL references and ALL "non reference values" are both blanket impls (and so would be conclificting)

Comment: The number of `ToOwned` impls is not that big; do you really need to automate that?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The number of `ToOwned` implementations *in the standard library* is not too big. But ideally it generalizes to any implementation, including those made in third-party code.